# jQuery Tools - Slideshow & Tabs linking problem

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am using jQuery Tools Slideshow & Tabs for a project I am working on. Right now everything works great and as it should. Currently each tab (li) is what changes the images in the #slide div. The problem I am having is that I have an external link inside each li (Read More Button) which links to another page in the site. Because the link resides inside each li, it doesn't work.

Has anybody else come across this problem or have any suggestions on how to get links to work inside the tabs? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out myself. I added this to specify the "read more" link inside the li:

```
$("#tabs li > span").click(function() {
  window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
  $("#slides > div").fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
```

I added the fadeTo because while the next page was loading, it was fading weird, this way it makes it 100% opacity while the next page loads.

There might be a better way for this but this worked perfectly for me.